# Scanner.hasNextLong Error

Tags: java, crash, java.util.scanner, long-integer, digits

Hello and thanks in advance,

I'm having a problem with the java.util.Scanner Here is my code:

```
public static void ScanInput(String Choice) {

    if(scanner.hasNextLong()){

        long input = scanner.nextLong();
        long length = String.valueOf(input).length();

        if(length <= 10){

            if(Choice == Choice1){

                Converter.Decimal(input);

            } else if(Choice == Choice2) {

                Converter.Binary(input);

            }
        } else {

            System.out.println(error);

            scanner.close();

            ScanInput(DecimalToBinary.choice);
        }


    } else {

        System.out.println(error);

        scanner.close();

        ScanInput(DecimalToBinary.choice);

    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

the use of this does not really matter. The problem is that when i enter an value bigger than 10 digits it crashes. So it seems that i used an int or so??

(Because of the maximum size of an int).

BUT I used long....

My debug instructor points at

if(scanner.hasNextLong()){

And that is also the place where things go to shit...
Please help!

Comment: *bigger than 10 digits* How big exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is bigger than 9223372036854775807(MAX value for long) then use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), something like this:

```
if (scanner.hasNextBigInteger()) {
   BigInteger big = scanner.nextBigInteger();
}
```

Right now the compiler is treating your input as integer as apparently your long input doesn't have suffix L. In java long ends with L, e.g:

```
long lg = 24863512789L;
```

Fix this and it'll work fine.

Comment: point is... that it is not bigger than that.... so i dont understand why long does not work

Comment: I can't see you initializing the scanner, Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: i did initialize it and yes it does work for less than 10 digits @AamirYousuf